# Docker images not updating autmatically

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build the automated builds in our Bitbucket and Docker and I was expecting that if I pushed a code on my repo then the codes on my container with my image will also change but seems like the automated build does not work like this

So I tried doing a pull on my image and when I checked my container.. It's still the same code. I tried running the container and checking the code of the changed file like this

```
docker-compose run <container> cat <project>/file.py
```

And it changed.. I'm a little confuse on why this occurs..

Did I do something wrong or was this kind of behavior in Docker intentional?

Comment: please refer at this post; i solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/26548914/7438356

Comment: So there's no such automated way? You need to do some extra scripting/commands