# Build Docker image only if Base Image has been modified since last build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let's say we have a dockerfile which contains a base image directive pointing to BaseImage:

```
FROM BaseImage
...
```

Is there any way so we can detect if BaseImage has been modified since the last build, so we can avoid building the image again?

Answer (score 0):

There was a previous question similar to this asking "[How to automatically update your docker containers, if base-images are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423515/how-to-automatically-update-your-docker-containers-if-base-images-are-updated?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)".

There is no standard way, but the user who answered ([bsuttor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506070/bsuttor)) submitted the script he uses to check for updates to the base image in the Docker repo:

> We use a script which checks if a running container is started with the latest image. We also use upstart init scripts for starting the docker image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
BASE_IMAGE="registry"
REGISTRY="registry.hub.docker.com"
IMAGE="$REGISTRY/$BASE_IMAGE"
CID=$(docker ps | grep $IMAGE | awk '{print $1}')
docker pull $IMAGE

for im in $CID
do
    LATEST=`docker inspect --format "{{.Id}}" $IMAGE`
    RUNNING=`docker inspect --format "{{.Image}}" $im`
    NAME=`docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' $im | sed "s/\///g"`
    echo "Latest:" $LATEST
    echo "Running:" $RUNNING
    if [ "$RUNNING" != "$LATEST" ];then
        echo "upgrading $NAME"
        stop docker-$NAME
        docker rm -f $NAME
        start docker-$NAME
    else
        echo "$NAME up to date"
    fi
done
```

> And init looks like

```
docker run -t -i --name $NAME $im /bin/bash
```