# How to automatically upgrade a running Docker container without any downtime

Tags: git, spring-boot, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Spring boot application. A Docker image is created with the jar file of that Spring boot application and is run by Jenkins on a UAT server. What happens is, whenever there are some code-changes being pushed into a git repo, a new Docker image is created by Jenkins and is run on that UAT server by Jenkins. How can this running Docker container be updated/upgraded automatically without any downtime?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423515/how-to-automatically-update-your-docker-containers-if-base-images-are-updated

Comment: Typical practice is to deploy a second container alongside the first one, and use a load balancer in front of them to avoid downtime during the upgrade.  Cluster environments like Kubernetes can automate this for you.

Comment: Thanks all for their inputs! 
@DavidMaze, can you please point some good resources/docs on how Kubernetes does this?