# How to improve automation of running container's base image updates?

Tags: docker, security, automatic-updates

I want all running containers on my server to always use the latest version of an official base image e.g. `node:16.3` in order to get security updates. To achieve that I have implemented an image update mechanism for all container images in my registry using a CI workflow which has some limitations described below.

I have read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423515/how-to-automatically-update-your-docker-containers-if-base-images-are-updated) but they either involve building or inspecting images on the target server which I would like to avoid.

I am wondering whether there might be an easier way to achieve the container image updates or to alleviate some of the caveats I have encountered.

### Current Image Update Mechanism

I build my container images using the `FROM` directive with the minor version I want to use:

```
FROM node:16.13
COPY . .
```

This image is pushed to a registry as `my-app:1.0`.

To check for changes in the `node:16.3` image compared to when I built the `my-app:1.0` image I periodically compare the SHA256 digests of the layers of the `node:16.3` with those of the first n=(number of layers of `node:16.3`) layers of `my-app:1.0` as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927907). I retrieve the SHA256 digests with `docker manifest inpect <image>:<tag> -v`.

If they differ I rebuild `my-app:1.0` and push it to my registry thus ensuring that `my-app:1.0` always uses the latest `node:16.3` base image.

I keep the running containers on my server up to date by periodically running `docker pull my-app:1.0` on the server using a cron job.

### Limitations

- When I check for updates I need to download the manifests for all my container images and their base images. For images hosted on Docker Hub this unfortunately counts against the [download rate limit](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/#definition-of-limits).
- Since I always update the same image `my-app:1.0` it is hard to track which version is currently running on the server. This information is especially important when the update process breaks a service. I keep track of the updates by logging the output of the `docker pull` command from the cron job.
- To be able to revert the container image on the server I have to keep previous versions of the `my-app:1.0` images as well. I do that by pushing incremental patch version tags along with the `my-app:1.0` tag to my registry e.g. `my-app:1.0.1`, `my-app:1.0.2`, ...
- Because of the way the layers of the base image and the app image are compared it is not possible to detect a change in the base image where only the uppermost layers have been removed. However I do not expect this to happen very frequently.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I'd do to simplify this.

`docker pull` already does essentially the sequence you describe, of downloading the image's manifest and then downloading layers you don't already have.  If you `docker build` a new image with an identical base image, an identical Dockerfile, and identical `COPY` source files, then it won't actually produce a new image, just put a new name on the existing image ID.  So it's possible to unconditionally `docker build --pull` images on a schedule, and it won't really use additional space.  (It could cause more redeploys if neither the base image nor the application changes.)

> [...] this unfortunately counts against the download rate limit.

There's not a lot you can do about that beyond running your own mirror of Docker Hub or ensuring your CI system has a Docker Hub login.

> Since I always update the same image my-app:1.0 it is hard to track which version is currently running on the server. [...]  To be able to revert the container image on the server [...]

I'd recommend always using a unique image tag per build.  A sequential build ID as you have now works, date stamps or source-control commit IDs are usually easy to come up with as well.  When you go to deploy, always use the full image tag, not the abbreviated one.

```sh
docker pull registry.example.com/my-app:1.0.5
docker stop my-app
docker rm my-app
docker run -d ... registry.example.com/my-app:1.0.5
docker rmi registry.example.com/my-app:1.0.4
```

Now you're absolutely sure which build your server is running, and it's easy to revert should you need to.

(If you're using Kubernetes as your deployment environment, this is especially important.  Changing the text value of a Deployment object's `image:` field triggers Kubernetes's rolling-update mechanism.  That approach is much easier than trying to ensure that every node has the same version of a shared tag.)